# Arduino as ISP for ATtiny

Tags: arduino, attiny, ide

I am attempting to use an Arduino Duemilanove as a tool to program an ATtiny85 from the Arduino IDE.

I was using the instructions at [ForkRobotics](http://www.forkrobotics.com/2012/04/run-arduino-code-on-an-attiny/) which are ...

- Upload ArduinoISP sketch to Arduino
- Connect Arduino pins 7, 8 & 9 to LEDS (heartbeat, error, programming)
- Connect Arduino Pins 10,11,12,13 to ATtiny85 pins 1,5,6,7 (plus 5V & GND)
- Download Arduino Tiny code from http://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/downloads/list
- Select Tools -> Board -> ATtiny85 (w/Arduino as ISP)
- Select Tools -> Programmer -> Arduino as ISP
- Load the example basic blink sketch (s/pin 13/pin 4/) to the ATtiny85

I can see the ArduinoISP heartbeat LED pulsing but at the last step I get the following errors

```
Blink.ino:10:21: error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
Blink.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Blink:15: error: 'OUTPUT' was not declared in this scope
Blink:15: error: 'pinMode' was not declared in this scope
```

Arduino.h *does* exist in   `...\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino`
but *not* in (for example) `...\Arduino\hardware\attiny45_85\cores\attiny45_85`

I made the following exceptions to the process described above ...

- I already had an old 2009 Arduino IDE installed so I started by downloading the latest stable Arduino IDE and installed it in a new directory. I opted not to install USB drivers.
- I wasn't sure which download to pick from the code.google URL so used [attiny45_85.zip](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1229) from hlt.media.mit.edu instead.

**Should there be a ATtiny85-specific Arduino.h in `...\Arduino\hardware\attiny45_85\cores\attiny45_85`?**
**What have I done wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround in an [Arduino forum thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=82220.0)

Create an Arduino.h in `...\Arduino\hardware\attiny45_85\cores\attiny45_85` containing

```
#include <WProgram.h>
```

I still get warning messages

```
avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part ATtiny85
avrdude: please define PAGEL and BS2 signals in the configuration file for part ATtiny85
```

but my tiny multi-million-transistor CPU can now wonderously make a LED blink.

[image]
<sup>*somewhere, an AVR engineer is crying into his beer*</sup>

It seems that the ATtiny45_85 setup for the Arduino IDE was affected by some sort of reorganisation in the internals when Arduino IDE 1.0 was developed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I finally solve it with this page:

http://www.lbruning.com/shop/2013/06/25/using-arduino-as-isp/

In particular, my error was that:

Tools > Board > ATtiny 45 (internal 8 MHz clock)
Tools > Serial Port > Select Port
Tools > Programmer > Arduino as ISP
¡¡Tools > Burn Bootloader!!

Comment: Link is dead as of 8/25/2014